# Celery : Will a retry block the queue

Tags: celery, task

Sorry I'm a beginner and I'm struggling to understand what are probably basics of Celery but I was wondering if a retry could block the queue of tasks.

For examples

```
@app.task(default_retry_delay=360, max_retries=100)
def myTask()
   try:
    Test.go()
   except Exception
    raise self.retry(countdown=20 + self.request.retries **4)


class Test
def go():
   Raise Exception()
```

If i call myTask three times, will I have three diffent task being retried at the same time or will the first Task block the next ones till there s no retry?

Thanks gor your help

Comment: Did you ever find a conclusive answer, @Jean?